# create a qt widget which provides options to select when pressed

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a qt project and right now I am stuck at one point where I need to write code to develop a custom widget which looks like as shown in the picture custom widget:

[image]

here i need to create a widget named UP which shows the options UP and DN to select as shown in the picture, whenever the user presses that widget.

I need to use this kind of widget at many places in the application with different options and different numbers of options.

One more thing I need to add here is that the options shown are themselves custom widgets, which I have already developed and these custom widgets have their own properties (like blink when selected).

Can anybody help me in deciding how can i create this kind of custom widget in qt? A sample code will be much help to me.

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem ?, shows the code you have tried to create that widget, SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Read about the QComboBox

Comment: @eyllansec, I am new to qt and I have not much idea about how or which functionalities of qt I should use in this case. I want some opinions about designing this widget

Comment: In SO we answer specific problems, we are not a service of tutoring or opinions, those topics are off-topic, I think you are resorting to an inappropriate place. Check [ask] so you know what questions are accepted here.

Comment: "I am new to qt" - In this case you should start here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html